# Can't go to LogIn activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building an app where I have LogIn activity.  And when user is logged, I want to when he exit from app and again opens it to skip LogIn activity and  immediately goes on Fragment on Main Activity. And when I am in the fragment when I click back button it sends me to the LogIn activity. To fix that I put finish() in checking shared preference token. And when user clicks back button he does not go to the LogIn activity because that activity is killed. But when I press "logOut" button on Fragment it should sends me to the LogInactivity but that don't works because that Activity is killed

My code for that is:

Main activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(sharedPreferences.getString("status", "logged_in").equals("logged_in")){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        viewToken = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tokenView);
        String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("result");
        //  viewToken.setText(data);

        initializeInjector();
        initialize();
    }
```

Login activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("Token pref",LoginActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("status", "logged_in");
    editor.commit();
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(mainActivity);

    credentials = new Credentials();
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            username = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            password = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

            String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (getUsername.length()>0 && getPassword.length()>0 ) {
                credentials.setUsername(getUsername);
                credentials.setPassword(getPassword);

                allOperations();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_fields , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void check() {
    SharedPreferences shf = getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strPref = shf.getString("token", null);
    if (strPref != null) {

        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Logout fragment:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Context context = inflater.getContext();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wrong_user, container, false);

    messageForWrongUser = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.wrongUser);
    buttonOk = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);

    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Token Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", "value");
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

What should I change to make that when user logs out that sends him to the LogIn activity and when he doesn't log out (just exit from app on home button) next time when he comes in to the app, he comes there where he was last time(for example:Fragment)?

This is logcat for leon's example:

```
07-21 15:50:49.835 5935-5935/com.telnet.asp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
                                                              at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:114)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                           Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
                                                              at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:192)
                                                              at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219)
                                                              at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                           Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
                                                              at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:192) 
                                                              at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120) 
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276) 
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219) 
                                                              at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                           Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
                                                              at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java)
                                                              at android.util.Slog.e(Slog.java)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java)
                                                              at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                              at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
                                                              at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:118)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                           Caused by: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
                                                              at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:43)
                                                              at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:38)
                                                              at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
                                                              at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OperatorMap.java:99)
                                                              at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                                                              at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
                                                              at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                                                              at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
                                                              at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
                                                              at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                                                              at rx.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:104)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate found in causal chain so cropping to prevent loop ...
                                                              at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java)
                                                              at android.util.Slog.e(Slog.java)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java)
                                                              at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                            at java.lang.ThreadG
```

Comment: You need to use shared preference for knowing whether the user is logged in or not. By checking that flag you can direct him.

Comment: That is okay, I have done it..but my problem is when I press logOut button it does not send me to the LogIn activity, because there I have that function check() that killes LogIn activity..

Comment: Why are you using check() function

Comment: @AjinkyaS agree with you

Comment: @Atenica show your `check()`

Comment: I have edited my question and you can see now what is really my problem, and my function check you have in the code

Comment: at first make sure that `check()` calling or not

Comment: Yes it is called...when I click back button it doesn't sends me to the LogIn activity instead of that it exit from app...that is how i know that check is called..

Comment: But my problem is when I press log out button it does not sends me to the LogIn activity because of this method finish()...

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick() of login button use like this
{
 Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
}

// when u r using welcom screen before login, u can do like this. Use shared prefernece. If flag is true then open Mainscreen or else open login screen.


Preferences  prfs= new Preferences(this);

if(prfs.getBoolean(KEY)){    
      Intent i = new Intent(WelcomScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(i);    
       finish();
}
else{
 Intent i = new Intent(WelcomScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);    
 startActivity(i);    
 finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Token pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Token Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

because you are creating new preference file and "token" doesn't exist there. So, remove token when user tap LogOut start `LoginActivity` and finish `MainActivity`

then, in `LoginActivity` check only if token exist

```
 SharedPreferences shf = getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String strPref = shf.getString("token", null);
 if (strPref != null) {
 Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but you have told me that I change mine line with yours but they are the same, doesn't they?

Comment: And this is all okay, but when i click logOut button it does not happening anything...

Comment: What happens when you click logOut? Your code seems that first remove token, then launch a new `LoginActivity` e finish() the current.

Comment: When I click logOut it adds me the same fragment as this where is logOut button...And If I 5 times press logOut it shows me this fragment for five times

Comment: It's strange, in your logOut code I can't see no fragment addition.

Comment: Yeah I know that is strange...but maybe I had bad explanation...when i press that button I always stay on that fragment, I dont go to LogIn activity...

Comment: Sorry mate let just forget that I write this about adding new fragment...It just LogOut dont works..it should delete token and then launching new Login activity and finishing this current activity, but with this my code it doesn't work nothing...

Comment: Check if after a logOut, `LoginActivity` is created. Maybe creating LoginActivity is too fast than `apply()` method, and when it checks if is user is already logged, returns true. Try to replace it with `commit()`.

Comment: What exception log?

Comment: I have posted log, please check

Comment: I think it's not related to `commit()`.

Comment: No mate, it doesn't help anything..:(

Comment: When I am checking token in SHared preferences in onCreate on MainActivity it is null. But then when it comes to if  token  again has value, it isn't null and that is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you a simple example .Let say You have two activity  `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity` .

In `LoginActivity` , you can save a value in `SharedPreferences` like the example below .

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("tagName", LoginActivity.this.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString("status", "logged_in");
                                    editor.commit();


Intent mainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(mainActivity)
```

And in  `onBackPressed` method of your `LoginActivity` do this , so when user press backbutton it simply exit the app

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

No in `onCreate` method of your `MainActivity` , check the `SharedPreferences`  value

```
       sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("tagName", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//check if value exist
            if(sharedpreferences.getString("status", "").toString().equals("")){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

If value exist then ok , otherwise redirect user to `LoginActivity`

and your logout function should be like this

```
public void logOut(){
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("tagName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
               editor.clear();
               editor.commit();
            Intent loginactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            loginactivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            loginactivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            loginactivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(loginactivity);
}
```

So after logout user will be redirected to `LoginActivity`

**EDIT**

The `onCreate` method of login activity will be look like this . I think that you are doing the login process in `allOperations()` method .  Please use the code to save value in `SharedPreferences`  and Redirect to MainActivity just after finishing your login process  .

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        startActivity(mainActivity);

        credentials = new Credentials();
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                username = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                password = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

                String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

                if (getUsername.length()>0 && getPassword.length()>0 ) {
                    credentials.setUsername(getUsername);
                    credentials.setPassword(getPassword);

                    allOperations();

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("token_pref", LoginActivity.this.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("status", "logged_in");
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_fields , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And the `onCreate` method of MainActivity will be like this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("token_pref", MainActivity.this.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(!sharedPreferences.getString("status","").equals("logged_in")){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    viewToken = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tokenView);
    String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("result");
    //  viewToken.setText(data);

    initializeInjector();
    initialize();
}
```

Comment: Should I put some If clause in Login activity for checking shared pref. or I just wrote like you did?

Comment: just try my code , hope it will work . If anything wrong let me know it

Comment: Well I used your code exactly like you wrote(I copied into my project) but when app is build it receives fatal error and app is closed

Comment: Could you share your full code MainActivity and LoginActivity  and the manifest file ? Did you declare the variable sharedpreferences ?  You hav declare it first like SharedPreferences sharedpreferences , at the top of the class .

Comment: Check my edited answer . Be sure there is onBackpressed method in LoginActivity

Comment: It doesn't recognize Intent mainActivity in getActivity(mainActivity) in onCreate in Login activity...